# Codeblocks Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c++, vector, codeblocks

New to C++ and am trying to learn on codeblocks on MacOSX. I've seen this question asked a lot, however it often seems that the answer is something within the coding itself. But this issue will randomly pop up while making the simplest of programs, often without any changing of the code.

below is the code that i've had issues with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace::std;

void TT_Default(vector<string> board);
void TT_Display(vector<string>& rboard);

int main()
{
    vector<string> board;
    vector<string>& rboard=board;

    TT_Default(rboard);

    for (vector<string>::iterator iter=board.begin(); iter<board.end(); ++iter)
        {
        cout << '\n' << *iter << endl;
        };
    return 0;
}

void TT_Default(vector<string>& rboard)
{
rboard.push_back("NW");
rboard.push_back("N");
rboard.push_back("NE");
rboard.push_back("W");
rboard.push_back("C");
rboard.push_back("E");
rboard.push_back("SW");
rboard.push_back("S");
rboard.push_back("SE");
}
```

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Answer (score 3):

You have a *declaration* and a *definition* of `TT_Default`.

In the *declaration* you use:

```
void TT_Default(vector<string> board);
```

In the *definition* you use:

```
void TT_Default(vector<string>& rboard)
```

You have to make them the same. For your purposes, make the *declaration* accept a reference, `vector<string>&`. This solves the issue.